# Tahiti Nui hotel swimming pool

Tags: hotels, swimming, tahiti

Does the Tahiti Nui Hotel have a swimming pool? Are there other budget hotels in Papeete that have one?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [TripAdvisor](http://www.tripadvisor.ca/Hotel_Review-g294352-d1523863-Reviews-Hotel_Tahiti_Nui-Papeete_Tahiti_Society_Islands.html) reviews and photographs, and [booking.com page](http://www.booking.com/hotel/pf/tahiti-nui.en-gb.html) for the hotel, and the hotel's [own web site](http://www.tahitinuihotelpapeete.com/index.htm?lbl=yh-en), yes. However one TripAdvisor review mentions that outside fitness classes come and use the pool, so it's not always available to guests.